# log4j2 - URISyntaxException when specifying path to configuration file

Tags: java, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I am using log4j2 in a web application and have the configuration file in my user home. I have specified the location in the web.xml as described in the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>file://${user.home}/someDirectory/log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Unfortunately, on a Windows system, I am getting a

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://C:\Users\steinman/someDirectory/log4j2.xml
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:46)
    ...
```

because of the backslashes. The documentation doesn't help here, because in the example there are also backslashes, which is just wrong.

Is there any solution?

I cannot hardcode the path using slashes because the application will run on other systems as well.

I don't want to put the log4j2.xml inside the application, because actually I have several applications running in a Tomcat and I want to use only one configuration file to configurate them all. And of course, on different systems I want to use different logging configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You may have found a bug. Can you raise a ticket for this (incl. all details) in the log4j2 issue tracker?

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2